# Permute the derivative, integral and the inner product

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

I forgot the theorems or the proposition that allow the operator D (derivative) to enter inside the integral and the one allow the inner product to enter inside too

$D L(x) \cdot v=\int_{0}^{\infty} D\left(\left\|e^{s A} x\right\|^{2}\right) \cdot v d s$

with  $L(x) =\int_{0}^{\infty} \left\|e^{s A} x\right\|^{2}d s$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign